# How to use a variable inside one class/method inside another class?

Tags: java, class, variables

could anyone help me, how to pass a variable inside one class inside a method to another class, so that I can continue to work with it? I mean for example timeValue from the code below on pictures. Thanks a lot, I did not manage to to get it to work correctly, even i tried hard.

```
package chattie;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.List;

public class ChatReader {

    public List<String> read(File file) {
        // public List<String> timeValue;
        File path = file;
        List<String> timeValue = null;

        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(String.valueOf(path)))) {
            String content = lines.collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
            String deleter = content.replaceAll("Time:", "").replaceAll("Name:", "").replaceAll("Message:", "");
            String line = deleter;
            String[] completeArray = line.split("\n");

            int l = completeArray.length;
            String[] arrayOnlyValues = new String[l];

            for (int i = 0; i < completeArray.length; ++i) {
                arrayOnlyValues[i] = completeArray[i];
            }

            List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(completeArray));
            arrayList.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null));

            List<String> list1 = arrayList;
            int[] t = {0};
            timeValue = list1.stream()
                    .filter(x -> t[0]++ % 3 == 0)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println(timeValue);

            int[] n = {2};
            List<String> list2 = arrayList;
            List<String> nameValue = list2.stream()
                    .filter(x -> n[0]++ % 3 == 0)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println(nameValue);

            int[] m = {1};
            List<String> list3 = arrayList;
            List<String> messageValue = list3.stream()
                    .filter(x -> m[0]++ % 3 == 0)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println(messageValue);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Code is text. Please [edit] your question and post it as text, not as pictures.

Comment: done, could you help me out ? thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do with `timeValue`. What do you mean "pass a variable inside one class inside a method to another class"? Either you pass it to a method as a parameter, or you expose it from its own class and the other class accesses it.

Comment: Let's say inside timeValue is [12:23:37, 14:24:11, 07:34:22]. I can use it inside the "old" class. But how can I use the "timeValue" inside a new class, let's call that "TEST" class. How can I transfer the variable timeValue with it's content to the new "TEST" class?

Comment: Depends on what you need to do with it afterwards.

Comment: I want to use the variable again inside the new class.... and work with it, let's make it a simple example and let's say I would like to make the timeValue +1h later.

Comment: Per your code snippet, why are you returning null instead of timeValue on the method read()?

Comment: I also tried to return timeValue, but still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You could just return `timeValue` from the method:

```
public List<String> read(File file) {
    List<String> timeValue = null;

    ...  // instantiate timeValue

    return timeValue;
}
```

Then call it from another class/method:

```
class foo {
    public void getTimeValue() {
        List<String> timeValue = ChatReader().read(file);
    } 
}
```

Comment: this method did not work for me, the second part call from another class.... it doesnt know what to do with "file" , it is an unknown paramter and highlighted in red in intellij.

Comment: Yes, you need to pass it a `file` when you call read. Where were you calling `read()` from before?

Comment: But the file is file... so If I understand correctly "file" should be passed and it is, because that's the name,  but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Hii declare value as a member of class not as the member of method(). Your code should be like this:

```
  class aaa    {
        String value="good luck";
         String txt="Best of luck";
       void mthod(){
                               }
                 }
 class bbb    {
        aaa obj=new aaa();
         bbb(){//constructor
         System.out.println(obj.value);
 }
     public static void main(String args[]){
    bbb obj2=new bbb();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried, but the only thing it returned was "null". That is not correct. It should return the old values [12:23:37, 14:24:11, 07:34:22] .